# Using tunnel diode to cancel out armature resistance

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, ac-motor, negative-resistance

Can we use tunnel diodes to cancel out armature resistance?

A tunnel diode when it is in its negative differential region under DC shifted AC(AC with some DC offset) and if the Vp-p of the AC is very small behaves like a resistor with negative resistance.

Usually the absolute value of this negative resistance is really small ~ 1Ω so we cant use it to cancel out the resistance of lets say a lamp BUT the armature resistance of a AC motor is in the range of 1Ω so in that way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBMM0n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since \$I\$ would become very big , the motor would rotate very very fast so I suspect it would reach saturation.Am I correct?

Comment: The tunnel diode has a negative *incremental* resistance, you can't use it to cancel copper resistance and create a superconductor. (If that's the question, it's not 100% clear to me.)

Comment: Yes in DC.Under AC its differential resistance is negative.The resistance in DC \$\ne\$ the resistance in AC.

Comment: Think of a tunnel diode as an "overacting dynamic resistor". When the voltage across it increases, it increases (but to a greater extent) its resistance, and v.v. In this way, it modulates the current in the circuit and, accordingly, the voltage drop created across the load. This is what we call "amplification". So the tunnel diode acts as the transistor but it is a 2-terminal device connected in series to the input voltage source, power supply and the load.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist but I can prove out that a tunnel diodes has in some range AC negative resistance I will load it up.

Comment: I think you might be confusing "AC resistance" with reactance and are inventing a capacitor.

Comment: Rut, The tunnel diode is not an AC device; it is a DC device - a "self-variable resistor" that changes its resistance simultaneously with the input voltage applied across it. It is a very simple and intuitive idea that can be modeled still in 19th century by a man moving the wiper of a rheostat. The question is how to model it in CircuitLab since there is no such conceptual element there...

Comment: I have to add some more thoughts as food for your mind. If your goal is to zero an unwanted resistance (your case), this can be done by connecting in series the dual S-shaped resistance (e.g., a neon lamp). The tunnel diode is an N-shaped negative resistance that is connected in parallel to a positive resistance; the result is infinite resistance.

Comment: @vir no I am not.I m not talking about impedance.DC resistance is not AC resistance.

Comment: About "Since I
 would become very big , the motor would rotate very very fast", it would happen if the negative resistance prevails. So the result of this neutralization has to be some small (close to zero) positive resistance; then "it would reach saturation". The pure negative resistance is something like the *self-reinforced positive feedback* in latching circuits (flip-flops).

Answer (score 2):

## Revealing the secret of negative differential resistance by CircuitLab experiments

### Experimental setup

According to my comments above, two resistors are connected in parallel - R1k with a 1 kΩ "positive" resistance, and R-1k with a  1 kΩ "negative" resistance. I have put both names in square quotes because these resistances are neither negative nor positive, but the most common ohmic resistance known since the 19th century. So the negative differential resistance of -1 kΩ is implemented by a variable resistor whose resistance changes from 111 Ω to infinity when Vin varies from 1 V to 10 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW2fMf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We need to observe the currents flowing through the resistors. To simplify the schematics, we can combine the resistors with the ammeters into one device ("visualized resistor"). To do this, open the *parameters* window of each of the two ammeters and set the corresponding internal resistance.

### Step-by-step experiments

To understand the mechanism of this so-called "N-shaped negative differential resistance", let's first examine the circuit at three successive values ​​of the input voltage - 1, 2 and 3 V.

**Vin = 1 V, R-1k = 100 Ω:** At 1 V input voltage, the 1 k positive resistor consumes 1 mA. The negative resistor has a 111 Ω resistance, so 9 mA current flows through it, and the total current consumed is 10 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flZzg3.png)</sup>

**Vin = 2 V, R-1k = 222 Ω.** When the input voltage increases to 2 V, the negative resistor increases its ohmic resistance to 250 Ω. Now the positive resistor consumes 2 mA but the negative 8 mA, and the total current consumed is again 10 mA (i.e., the left current increases but the right current decreases, and their sum I remains constant).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSrlh.png)</sup>

**Vin = 3 V, R-1k = 375 Ω:** Next, the input voltage increases to 3 V, and the negative resistor increases its ohmic resistance to 428 Ω. The positive resistor consumes 3 mA but the negative 7 mA, and the total current consumed is, as usual, 10 mA... and so on...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNOTaA.png)</sup>

### Automated experiment

To sweep the negative resistance, we can simulate it using a *behavioral current source* I-1k that produces a current 10 mA - IR.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmEhjP.png)</sup>

### Graphical representation

From the graphs below, we see that as the input voltage increases, the current through the positive resistor increases and through the negative resistor decreases because its resistance increases. The result is a constant common current which is seen by the input voltage source as an infinite differential resistance.

[image: STEP 3]

## Applications

I will illustrate my conceptual explanations above by solving a specific circuit problem - *eliminating the impact of the load on the output voltage of a voltage divider*.

### Experimental setup

In the schematic below, a potentiometer P is loaded by a 1 kΩ "positive" resistor RL. A 1 kΩ (N-shaped) negative differential resistor R with initial resistance of 200 Ω is connected in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f44Pxw.png)</sup>

**Vin = 5 V, R = 200 Ω:** As a result, a total current I = 6 mA is consimed from the potentiometer output, and its output voltage is 1 V. Note that to simplify the schematic, I have implemented the resistors with "bad" ammeters having the same internal resistance (RL1k = 1 kΩ, R = 200 Ω).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA4W5T.png)</sup>

**Vin = 6 V, R = 333 Ω:** When we increase Vin with 1 V, the potentiometer output voltage begins increasing. Simultaneously, the "negative" resistor R increases its resistance to 333 Ω thus compensating the influence of the positive load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdn5y9.png)</sup>

As a result, the output voltage becomes 1.5 V instead of 1.2 V as it would be if R had not increased:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQgIX.png)</sup>

**Vin = 7 V, R = 500 Ω:** When we increase Vin by another 1 V, the potentiometer output voltage begins increasing even more. The "negative" resistor R increases its resistance to 500 Ω thus compensating the influence of the positive load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa3OvA.png)</sup>

The output voltage becomes 2 V instead of 1.75 V as it would be if R had not increased:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyrLw4.png)</sup>

### Equivalent circuit

So, the voltage divider is loaded with a 6 mA constant current source I, and the output voltage variations are not influenced by this **extremely high-resistance load**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyoB2n.png)</sup>

## Conclusions

- The *N-shaped negative differential resistor* (e.g. a *tunnel diode*) is a *dynamic resistor* that increases its static (ohmic) resistance when the voltage across it increases.
- If connected in parallel to an equivalent "positive" resistor, it neutralizes its resistance so that the equivalent resistance is infinite.

So this is not what OP need. They need:

- a *dynamic resistor* that decreases its static (ohmic) resistance when the current through it increases.
- It will be connected in series to an equivalent "positive" resistor so that to neutralize its resistance, and make the equivalent resistance zero.

See also [another story of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/657230/61398) dedicated to this circuit phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that since it does not have absolute negative resistance.

We do use IR compensation in motor speed controls to negate armature resistance though. It's done with an electronic circuit, basically to measure the armature current and increase the voltage to compensate for the I*R drop- no weird components like Esaki diodes are required.

Ideally, it means the motor will maintain a constant speed proportional to applied voltage regardless of mechanical loading. Without such "IR compensation" the motor speed will drop as the load and therefore armature current increases.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, Of course, the tunnel diode implementation is not practically feasible, but the question is more conceptual, and consists in whether the goal can be achieved with such an element (negative differential resistor). By itself, it is a passive element (in the sense that it does not "produce" power). But I think that in combination with a source it becomes an absolute negative resistor, and can compensate for a positive resistance. This idea is difficult to realize even with an op-amp circuit of a true negative resistor (VNIC) because the current through the motor is very high.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I think if you start with a motor speed control where output voltage is proportional to input (either from a DC signal or a potentiometer) adding IR compensation does not require much additional complexity or difficulty. No additional high currents involved except maybe in measuring the armature current if a shunt resistor is used (rather than something like Hall effect).

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, the "IR compensation" is well known in negative feedback electronic circuits. For example, the popular op-amp circuit of a *transimpedance amplifier* is based on it. There an op-amp compensates for the IR drop across the feedback resistor R by adding a voltage of the same value in series and in the same direction with the input voltage. The result is zero voltage at the inverting input (*virtual ground*) and zero resistance between the inputs (*virtual short*). In this way, as though the R positive resistance is neutralized (zeroed) by the op-amp output "negative resistance".

Comment: Spehro Pefhany,  I understand you... but I hope you understand me too.  I am looking to derive and explain as general a principle (concept) as possible and not so specific a circuit solution. Otherwise, I have an idea of ​​the complexities in the theory and practice of this field...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I think the answers are complementary.